# How to implement Isotope - Elements Complete on the iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, core-animation

Please go to:
http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/elements-complete.html

I want to implement on the iPhone the **"Toggle variable size"** part.

To be more specific, I want to layout my 30+ photos (same size) on a scroll-view and i want it to look like **"Toggle variable size"** looks like.

The implementation needs to be native, I guess via view-controller or some table-view with custom cells.

Do you have any thoughts on whats the best way to implement this on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I will line out a very high level overview of how I would aproach your problem.

Create a custom scroll view subclass, lets say `TiledGridView`. For simplicity, let's assume that the interface looks like similar to this:

```
@interface TiledGridView : UIScrollView {
    NSArray *tileData;
}
@property(retain) NSArray *tileData;
- (void)layoutSubviews;
@end
```

The `tileData` array contains information about the tiles (location, size, and the image). You set `tileData` using the synthesized accessors in the simplest case. You can create a ViewController that actually calculates the positions of the tiles, or you can add a method in the view. For further discussion, lets assume that `tileData` contains all the data about the tiles we need, and that we already know their positions etc.

Then, the most important part is to override the `layoutSubviews` message in your subclass. In layoutSubviews you will do the following:

- check the bounds of the `TiledGridView`
- add `UIImageView`s (or whatever you like) for tiles that are within those bounds
- remove tiles outside the bounds

You do it so that you don't run out of memory when you have many images. This is also what UITableView does, but they even reuse views.

A pseudo-implementation could look similar to this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
  CGRect bounds = self.bounds;

  for (id tile in tileData) {
    if (/*tile is not yet visible and tile overlaps bounds*/) {
      UIView newTileView = /* create the view for the tile */
      [self insertSubview:newTileView atIndex:0];
   } else if (/*tile is visible and no longer overlaps bounds*/) {
      UIView oldTileView = /* fetch the corresponding view */
      [oldTileView removeFromSuperview];
    }
  }
```

This will make your view very fast, as subviews are added only as needed.

Comment: That is a very thoughts inspiring approach. Eventually I mainly used the "Scrolling" sample code from Apple as a reference.